# InternalResourceViewResolver not resolving views properly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have no idea what we're doing wrong here. I'm trying to set up a single page Spring MVC project so I can look into things. I have a single screen, `greeting.html` that I'm trying to load. Here's my controller class to load it:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String getGreeeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

This works fine when `greeting.html` is in `/resources/templates/greeeting.html`. However, I'd like it behind a `WEB-INF` folder. I've tried placing it in `WEB-INF/views/greeting.html` and `webapp/WEB-INF/views/greeting.html`. I then try and use an `InternalResourceViewResolver` as I've read online:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

From my understanding, this should allow it to find `greeting.html` behind one of my WEB-INF folder setups. However, when I go to `localhost:8080/greeting`, I get a 404 along with the following message in the console:

`WARN 1439 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/views/greeting.html]`

I'm at a complete loss as to what's even going on or how to fix it, every single tutorial online does this exact thing and has no problems, I can't seem to find anyone online with this same issue. Any guidance at all would be helpful here.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing **provided** or add **${tomcat-embed-jasper.scope}** in scope tag from **tomcat-embed-jasper** dependency . It helped for me.

Comment: can you please provide  additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your view resolver extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="...package name...")
@EnableWebMvc

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {

     InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
     viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
     viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

   return viewResolver;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the solutions but got the 404 error using Spring Boot 2.*.
For me, running the application using the command "`mvn clean spring-boot:run`" fixed the error

Comment: I had a hunch the project needed some cleaning!

Answer (score 2):

Hi as i understand from your question you are using spring boot 
By default spring boot searches for src/main/resources/templates folder 
If you used some dependency like :

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

This will enable thymeleaf by default.

To override you ViewResolver you need

In spring boot you can make such config in your application.properties file:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

or you can write custom resolver configuration with java config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }  
 }
```

I think this is helpful

Comment: I was thinking it would be something like that, however none of these solutions worked for me. Can you think of any other areas that may be causing it to still look in the resources folder?

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: @BillL are you packaging to jar or war ?
Do you use thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below dependency in your pom.xml. I have also got same error but after adding this dependency I can able to access the URL.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.52</version>
    </dependency>
```